# Wrong results when adding milliseconds to java.util.date object

Tags: java, date, java.util.date

Current time is `Sat Apr 04 15:02:00 AEST 2020`.

In the following snippet, I create a Date object and add 86400000L milliseconds (1 day) to it:

```
Date date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + 86400000L);
System.out.println(date);
```

The output is `Sun Apr 05 14:02:00 AEST 2020`. I don't understand why the result adds only 23 hours to my current time, instead of 24 hours.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @OleV.V. that is a good advice, but totally unrelated to the problem at hand, right?

Comment: Not really, @cherouvim. As I see it the questioner’s confusion comes from the poor design of the `Date` class. S/he should use `ZonedDateTime.plusDays(1)` to get their expected result without any confusion. I think this is pertinent to the request *Any help would be appreciated.* (apart from that I also believe that being helpful with anything else in the question has its place too).

Comment: It would help us help you if you pasted your exact observation into the question (rather than typing and risking an inaccuracy). If I have understood correctly, your current time was is **AEDT** (Australian Eastern Daylight Time) rather than AEST.

Comment: @OleV.V. And the time was `Sat Apr 04`, not `Sun Apr 04`.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Thanks for pointing, made the edit.

Answer (score 2):

The code works just fine. The `AEST` on your output means that the date regards `Australian Eastern Standard Time`. Googling for `AEST dst` shows that on Sunday, April 5, 3:00 am 2020 the clock will "go back" 1 hour. Thus adding 24 hours just before the DST change, will only move the time 23 hours forward.

If you run that code tomorrow, you'll not have this "problem".

Comment: Ahh, that explains a lot. Looks like today, of all days, was a bad time to test some of my code. Thanks!

Comment: Programming with dates is hard, so I think that today was a great day to test that code of yours, because that made you a better programmer.

Comment: Agreed. To be honest it does seem a bit weird (and ridiculous at the same time). The same code would work fine tomorrow. Also, the code would work just fine right now in some other country/timezone. Definitely need to check a lot of corner cases when dealing with dates.

Comment: The code works fine in all cases. This is not a programming problem. You are supposed to move your clock back 1 hour in a couple of hours in the place where you live. This is due to DST which people have agreed to follow. This has been correctly implemented by Java.

Answer (score 1):

Do use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

```
    ZonedDateTime currentTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Australia/Sydney"));
    System.out.println(currentTime);
    ZonedDateTime tomorrowSameTime = currentTime.plusDays(1);
    System.out.println(tomorrowSameTime);
```

Output when running just now:

> ```
> 2020-04-04T16:00:30.579484+11:00[Australia/Sydney]
> 2020-04-05T16:00:30.579484+10:00[Australia/Sydney]
> ```

Please observe: we got the same time of day tomorrow, 16:00. Because summer time (daylight saving time) ends, the UTC offset for tomorrow is different, +10:00 instead of +11:00. And importantly, while I find `+ 86400000L` pretty close to unreadable for adding a day, `.plusDays(1)` conveys the intention very clearly.

Please insert a different Eastern Australian time zone if required.

**What went wrong in your code?** cherouvim has explained this very nicely in the other answer, no need for me to repeat. Only allow me to add that the `Date` class is not only poorly designed — giving rise to your confusion — it is also long outdated. I recommend you don’t use it. And as cherouvim notes in a comment, programming with dates is hard. Don’t trust that you can yourself convert 1 day to 86 400 000 milliseconds. Leave all date and time calculations to proven library methods.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.